# try-with-resources文について

Tags: java

javaのtry-with-resources文についての質問です。

下記のように`try()`のカッコ外にオブジェクトを宣言した場合はコンパイルエラーとなりますか？

```
MyResource obj1;
try (obj1 = new MyResource("obj1")) {
    // 処理
} catch (SQLException e) {
   // 例外処理
}
```

Answer (score 1):

はい。コンパイルエラーになります。

[ドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)にあるように、

> try-with-resources 文は、1 つ以上の**リソースを宣言する try 文です**。

ただし、Javaの新しいバージョンでは[このページ](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/hishidama/home/tech/java/statement.html#try_with_resources_statement)にあるような書き方もできます。